# Use DataSet from C# code in a SSRS server report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008

I have a ReportViewer in an asp.net project which loads a report in
**ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote** (A *.rdl report that sits on an SSRS server)

I have a DataSet which was generated somewhere else and I want to push it into the report via code. How can I do that ? (In local mode ,*.rdlc, it seems pretty easy...)

Comment: How large is the dataset? Is it feasible to pass it as parameters for the report via `ReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters()`? Do you have any sample code for what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

first, create a Parameter in RDL.

Then in the dataset, put:

```
=Parameters!Example.value
```

The code to send a parameter, for example:

```
         ReportParameter parameter1 ReportParameter = new ("example", nameDataSet.toString);
         ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters (ReportParameter new [] {parameter1 });
```